# Orthonormality condition of polarization four-vectors

Tags: quantum-field-theory

In the scheme of covariant quantization of the electromagnetic field, it is assumed that the polarization four-vectors satisfy the orthonormality relation (QFT by Mandl & Shaw): $$\sum_r \varepsilon_{r\mu}(\vec k)\varepsilon^\mu_s(\vec k)=-\zeta_r\delta_{rs}$$ where $$\zeta_0=-1, \zeta_1=\zeta_2=\zeta_3=1.$$ I do not understand why the normalization is so strangely chosen! Why not set all the $\zeta_r$ to -1 so that the it takes the simpler form
$$\sum_r \varepsilon_{r\mu}(\vec k)\varepsilon^\mu_s(\vec k)=\delta_{rs}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice that you propose is not possible. You can change the sign of all $\zeta$, which is a matter of taste.